# How approximate are "approximate" nearest neighbor (ANN) search algorithms?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, search-algorithms, approximation, heuristics

Starting to use [nanoflann](https://code.google.com/p/nanoflann/) to do some point cloud nearest neighbor searching and it got me thinking about just how "approximate" ANN methods are.

If I have a (more or less) randomly distributed point cloud what is the likelihood that I get the exact nearest neighbor given a target point within the clouds bounding box?  I know that it is dataset dependent... but does anyone have a good numerical study somewhere that shows trends?

Comment: Which algorithm(s) are you interested in in particular? Have you done research? (It's unlikely people will dig into some tool documentation for you.)

Answer (score 2):

nanoflann is a library for building KD-trees.  For the [best bin first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_bin_first) (BBF) approximate nearest neighbor algorithm (which is based on KD-trees), the [authors report](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.23.9493) the following performance results:

> In 12 dimensions, for example, BBF recovers the closest neighbor 94%
>   of the time (versus 59% for restricted search) while on average
>   examining only 200 of the 100,000 leaf nodes. For this same case, the
>   “exact” search has to examine over 2400 leaves. [Even] when the method
>   does not discover the exact nearest neighbor, it does not fail by
>   much.  Even up to dimension 20, the average distance of recovered
>   neighbors is only 2% greater than the true NN distances.

However, that paper does not contain a formal analysis of the error bounds in this particular $\varepsilon$-approximation.